# How do I check the name of the game someone is playing

Tags: python, discord.py

So im trying to make a command that sends the name of the game you are playing

```
@client.event():
async def on_message(message):
  member = message.author
  guild = client.get_guild(id)
  channel = guild_get_channel(id)
  if message.author == client.user:
   return
  
  if message.content.startswith('!test'):
   await channel.send(f'you are playing {member.game}')
```

it gives me an error saying `'Member' object has no attribute 'game'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accsess a members activity with [Member.activity](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.activity) which could give you a [discord.BaseActivity](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.BaseActivity) if an activity is set.

Comment: I tried that but it just said "none" even to the 'member' was playing a game

Comment: enable presences intent